# MPV: how to get information about media being played through command line?

Tags: mpv

I want to get output containing info about title, state (playing/paused), current position, total time, etc., of the media currently being played in `mpv`.

In `mocp` player for example it's easy: `mocp -i` provides output like this:

```
State: PLAY
File: /home/piotr/muz/09 Svantetic.mp3
Title: 1 Możdżer - Svantetic (Komeda)
Artist: Możdżer
SongTitle: Svantetic
Album: Komeda
TotalTime: 03:35
TimeLeft: 03:22
TotalSec: 215
CurrentTime: 00:13
CurrentSec: 13
Bitrate: 235kbps
AvgBitrate: 236kbps
Rate: 44kHz
```

Is it possible to get such information in `mpv`?

UPDATE:

Seems it requires some lua scripting. Since I am not familiar with this language I would appreciate any hint. I am interested in a script which will provide info mentioned above when summoned from command line.

**UPDATE 2**

Apparently to get such an easy info in mpv one has to start mpv socket, and then extract data throug parsing JSON. For now I ended with quick and dirty solution (still can't believe that there is no built in functionality for this...):

`mpv <file> --input-ipc-server=/tmp/mpvsocket`

and a bash script:

```
POSITION=$(echo '{ "command": ["get_property_string", "time-pos"] }' | socat - /tmp/mpvsocket | jq .data | tr '"' ' ' | cut -d'.' -f 1)

REMAINING=$(echo '{ "command": ["get_property_string", "time-remaining"] }' | socat - /tmp/mpvsocket | jq .data | tr '"' ' ' | cut -d'.' 
-f 1)

METADATA=$(echo '{ "command": ["get_property", "filtered-metadata"] }' | socat - /tmp/mpvsocket | jq ".data.Artist, .data.Album, .data.Title")

echo $METADATA
printf '%d:%02d:%02d' $(($POSITION/3600)) $(($POSITION%3600/60)) $(($POSITION%60))
printf ' %d:%02d:%02d\n' $(($REMAINING/3600)) $(($REMAINING%3600/60)) $(($REMAINING%60))
```

Which gives output:

```
"Nils Frahm" "Felt" "Keep"
0:01:33 0:01:53
```

(note: METADATA works only for files with tags, to get info from online streaming one has to apply other commands; I use `jq` to parse JSON data from /tmp/mpvsocket)

Answer (score 1):

This mpv script [stats.lua](https://paste.debian.net/1203486) will show info of currently playing media by pressing i,I,1,2,3
name it stats.lua put in ~/.config/mpv/scripts/stats.lua, it will load each time you start mpv, if always load not desired do

mpv --script=~/.config/mpv/scripts/mynotify.lua /path/to/media.webm

(full path to script *might* be required)

Comment: paste.debian.net - entry not found

Comment: Is it perhaps the same as this one: https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/blob/master/player/lua/stats.lua If so, I'll update the link.